# Why is entity framework not loading my collection into the base class?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dynamic, entity-framework-6

I have a base object that inherits from `DynamicObject` that I'm using as a base class for my entity POCOs, which is allowing the POCO to work like an `ExpandoObject` (with a `Dictionary<string,object>` like object under the hood) I map that dictionary to an edm compatible Key/Value class like this:

```
public class EntityPair<TKey, TValue>
{
   [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public TKey Key { get; set; }
   public TValue Value { get; set; }
   public string TableName { get; set; }
   public int FK { get; set; }
}
```

and have strong typed inheriting classes for each system type we need to store, i.e.

```
public class EntityPairString: EntityPair<string,string> { }
```

and the base expando has a public property that will get all the dynamic properties of a type(like string) as it's corresponding key value type. For example, with string properties, it will return a collection of `EntityPairString` objects.

Now the issue I'm having is that it isn't loading the collection of a type (like the string collection) *back out* of the database - I can store it fine. but when I retrieve it, I can't get the string KVPair collection. What's odd about it is EF says it knows about the relationship, and loaded the collection, but it is not setting the collection - even if I eager or explictly load it.

The Entity:

```
public class Order : Expando
{
    public Order()
    {
        TableName = "Order";
    }

    public short OrderType { get; set; }
    public int InitiatorId { get; set; }
    public string InitiatorName { get; set; }

    [...]

    public class OrderConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Order>
    {
        public OrderConfiguration()
        {
            Map(c => c.MapInheritedProperties());
            HasMany(c => c.StringExpando)
                     .WithOptional()
                     .HasForeignKey(c => c.FK)
                     .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
        }
    }
}
```

The Expando it inherits:

```
[Serializable]
public class Expando : DynamicObject, IDynamicMetaObjectProvider
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    protected string TableName { get; set; }

    [...]

    public virtual ICollection<EntityPairString> StringExpando
    {
        get
        {
            var values = ((IEnumerable<EntityPair<string, object>>)Properties)
                .Where(c => c.Value is string)
                .Select(d => new EntityPairString()
                {
                    Key = d.Key,
                    Value = d.Value as string,
                    Id = d.Id,
                    FK = Id,
                    TableName = TableName
                }).ToList();
            return values;
        }
        set
        {
            if (Properties == null) Properties = new PropertyBag();
            foreach (var i in value)
            {
                var p = (EntityPair<string, string>)i;
                Properties.Add(new EntityPair<string, object>
                {
                    Id = i.Id,
                    Key = i.Key,
                    Value = i.Value,
                    FK = Id,
                    TableName = TableName
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Everything else is working, and like I said, I can add values to the database fine, what is not happening is loading the properties back from the database. the `Order` object comes back fine, but it does not load the string expando properties back.

Note: while my entity mapping in the `Order.OrderConfiguration` says that it is a foreign key, but I removed that from the explicit database migration. The relationship is indexed and still listed in EF's internals during runtime. I verified this by calling:

```
var relationshipManager = ((IObjectContextAdapter) ctx).ObjectContext
           .ObjectStateManager.GetRelationshipManager(order);
        var relations = relationshipManager.GetAllRelatedEnds();
```

So in simple, my question is why is my collection of `EntityPairString`'s not being attached to the `Order` object by EF when I load any or all `Order` entities?

For thoroughness:

the relevant parts of the explicit migration:

```
CreateTable(
    "dbo.expando_string",
     c => new
     {
         Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
         TableName = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
         FK = c.Int(nullable: false),
         Key = c.String(),
         Value = c.String(),
     })
     .PrimaryKey(t => new { t.Id, t.TableName, t.FK })
     .Index(t => t.FK);
```

**UPDATE**:

just in my debugging process I decided to confirm that it was generating the right query, so I did a SQL profile and the query it runs is:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
[Project2].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Project2].[OrderType] AS [OrderType], 
[Project2].[InitiatorId] AS [InitiatorId], 
[Project2].[InitiatorName] AS [InitiatorName], 
...
[Project2].[C1] AS [C1], 
[Project2].[Id1] AS [Id1], 
[Project2].[TableName] AS [TableName], 
[Project2].[FK] AS [FK], 
[Project2].[Key] AS [Key], 
[Project2].[Value] AS [Value]
FROM ( SELECT 
    [Limit1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Limit1].[OrderType] AS [OrderType], 
    [Limit1].[InitiatorId] AS [InitiatorId], 
    [Limit1].[InitiatorName] AS [InitiatorName], 
    ... 
    [Extent2].[Id] AS [Id1], 
    [Extent2].[TableName] AS [TableName], 
    [Extent2].[FK] AS [FK], 
    [Extent2].[Key] AS [Key], 
    [Extent2].[Value] AS [Value], 
    CASE WHEN ([Extent2].[Id] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS int) ELSE 1 END AS [C1]
    FROM   (SELECT TOP (1) 
        [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
        [Extent1].[OrderType] AS [OrderType], 
        [Extent1].[InitiatorId] AS [InitiatorId], 
        [Extent1].[InitiatorName] AS [InitiatorName], 
        ...
        FROM [dbo].[Orders] AS [Extent1]
        WHERE [Extent1].[Id] = @p__linq__0 ) AS [Limit1]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[expando_string] AS [Extent2] ON [Limit1].[Id] = [Extent2].[FK]
)  AS [Project2]
ORDER BY [Project2].[Id] ASC, [Project2].[C1] ASC',N'@p__linq__0 int',@p__linq__0=1
```

which does return the proper result set when executed, so somewhere inside the EF C# code it's just not attaching the entity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was wrong - EF doesn't set collections, it only adds or removes from them, it will initialize a collection if the getter returns null, but then it will still add to the collection it just initialized (which is why you can add an item before it lazy loads the rest of the collection)

So the issue was with this:

```
public virtual ICollection<EntityPairString> StringExpando
{
    get
    {
        var values = ((IEnumerable<EntityPair<string, object>>)Properties)
            .Where(c => c.Value is string)
            .Select(d => new EntityPairString()
            {
                Key = d.Key,
                Value = d.Value as string,
                Id = d.Id,
                FK = Id,
                TableName = TableName
            }).ToList();
        return values;
    }
    set
    {
        if (Properties == null) Properties = new PropertyBag();
        foreach (var i in value)
        {
            var p = (EntityPair<string, string>)i;
            Properties.Add(new EntityPair<string, object>
            {
                Id = i.Id,
                Key = i.Key,
                Value = i.Value,
                FK = Id,
                TableName = TableName
            });
        }
    }
}
```

I had to do some restructuring but I eventually got it to work by actually returning the collection, so when it added to the collection I would be aware of it.

Simply put, it was a silly mistake on my part, EF was actually setting the values for me already, but it was setting them in a list that I had no handle to.

What the final method looks like that EF uses to save and fetch the collections:

```
    public ICollection<ExpandoString> StringExpando
    {
        get
        {
            // ReSharper disable ForCanBeConvertedToForeach
            for (var i = 0; i < _strings.Count; i++)
            // ReSharper restore ForCanBeConvertedToForeach
            {
                _strings[i].FK = Id;
                _strings[i].TableName = TableName;
            }
            //using for as we don't want to enumerate the bag
            return _strings.List;
        }
    }
```

the only caveat of using expandable objects as entities is that you have to explicitly load all relationships on expandable entities, but, they are going to be light, so it shouldn't be a deal breaker.